# What is the difference between Collections from casted from a HashMap over entryset() and casted ArrayList for Jackson?

Tags: spring, rest, collections, casting, hashmap

I am developing a Spring Rest application. One of my methods is that:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
Collection<Configuration> getConfigurationInJSON() {
    Collection<Configuration> confList = new ArrayList<Configuration>();
...
```

I fill my confList and send it for GET request, it works. However when I want to keep that confList in a HashMap and send it after got it's entrySet as like that:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public
@ResponseBody
Collection<Configuration> getAllConfigurationsInJSON() {
    return configurationMap.values();
}
```

It gives me 406 error, so it means there is a wrong. What are the differences between that collections and why the second one is not same with first example?

Comment: Regarding the question title, there's no casting involved in your code whatsoever, so it's a little misleading.

Comment: @Costi Ciudatu edited the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of simplicity, can you just copy the `values()` collection?

```
new ArrayList<Configuration>(configurationMap.values());
```

Only thing that comes to my mind is that Spring expects mutable collection, but don't really understand why. Hard to say without debugging, try enabling `org.springframework.web` full logging.

Comment: Your solution works, thanks. However using new operator will duplicate the values at memory, is there any solution with casting or something like that cos I don't want to copy all the values to another variable?

Comment: @kamaci: That will not duplicate the values, it will only duplicate the references to them.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious difference is that `configurationMap.values()` is a `Set`.

You need to check if the JSON marshaller expects a `List` to be returned and is not able to marshal `Set` instances, as the marshaller will check the actual type of the returned value instead of the declared return type of the method, which is `Collection`.

By the way, isn't there any clue in the logs about this ?

Comment: Well, when I try to return List it works(and change method signature to Collection works too). However when I convert it to Collection it doesn't give any error at server side but at client side it gives me "406 Not Acceptable" error.

Comment: As I said, the return type doesn't matter for `@ResponseBody` annotated methods, as it will use an `HttpMessageConverter` that is able to handle your actual runtime type. If you're using Jackson, that will be `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter`. The `canRead()` method in this class reads the following: `return this.objectMapper.canDeserialize(javaType) && canRead(mediaType)`